# SQL update with html content

Tags: html, mysql, sql-update, mysql-error-1064

I need to search and replace something in a table:

Search value:

```html
<div class="row"><br /><br /><br />
<h4 style="color: #ff0000;">-&gt; text</h4><div><br /><div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-sp-12">
```

I have tried something like this:

```html
 UPDATE product_lang SET description = REPLACE (  description,  '<div class="row"><br /><br /><br />
    <h4 style="color: #ff0000;">-&gt; text</h4><div><br /><div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-sp-12">',  'replace text');
```

but it's not working

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE product_lang SET description = REPLACE (  description,  '

Comment: show the code please.

Comment: UPDATE product_lang SET description = REPLACE (  description,  '<div class="row"><br /><br /><br />
    <h4 style="color: #ff0000;">-&gt; Some text here</h4><div><br /><div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-sp-12">',  'replace text here');

Comment: If I have no html tags it works...UPDATE product_lang SET description = REPLACE (  description,  'some text',  'replace text');

Comment: are you using sql directly rather than through an application? If using SQL directly, look closer at those quotes to see if the"Some text here" contains quotes. If using application code, use prepared statements. Could even try this for SQL directly if you have trouble identifying the quotes.

Comment: I am using SQL directly and yes "Some text here" contains a lot of quotes....some text is this:

Comment: <div class="row"><br /><br /><br />
<h4 style="color: #ff0000;">-&gt; text</h4><div><br /><div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-sp-12">

Comment: As u can se some text contains a lot of quotes....